# Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

This error happened when i tried to add hashlocationstrategy

boot.ts

```
///<reference path="../typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { RootComponent } from "./root.component";
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import { PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, provide, enableProdMode } from "angular2/core";
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from "angular2/http";
import { FirebaseService } from "./shared/firebase.service";
import { Environment } from "./config/environment";

if (Environment === "production") {
  enableProdMode();
}


bootstrap(RootComponent, [
  FirebaseService,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(
    [PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi: true}],
    [LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
  )
])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Think its because my syntax of using both platform directives and locationstrategy like that is wrong. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There need to be separate `provide()` for both `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES` and `LocationStrategy`

```
bootstrap(RootComponent, [
  FirebaseService,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,

  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, multi: true}),
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})

  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: hmm then i get this in TS lint without the brackets `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.` and it won't compile

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: great this works thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to bootstrap your application this way:

```
bootstrap(RootComponent, [
  FirebaseService,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(
    PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi: true}),
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/6fXmPi?p=preview

Comment: hmm can you check this thread please? its mine and it works without hashstrategy `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878966/router-directives-in-two-places-for-same-purpose/35880222#35880222`

Comment: Yes you're right. I missed a part of your question. I think that you don't use the `provide` function the right way... I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Günter Zöchbauer answered the same already ;o

Comment: Yes, I saw that after having edited my answer ;-) You're welcome and pleased to see you got the answer of your problem! @Günter was quickier ;-)